# What does CVS stand for?

Tags: linux, rsync

What does CVS stand for? What does it mean? In particular, I mean the `--cvs-exclude` option in [rsync](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync).

```
-C, --cvs-exclude
    This is a useful shorthand for excluding a broad range of files that you often don't want to transfer between systems. It uses a similar algorithm to CVS to determine if a file should be ignored. 
The exclude list is initialized to exclude the following items (these
    initial items are marked as perishable -- see the FILTER RULES section): 
CWRCS SCCS CVS CVS.adm RCSLOG cvslog.* tags TAGS .make.state
    .nse_depinfo *~ #* .#* ,* _$* *$ *.old *.bak *.BAK *.orig *.rej .del-* *.a *.olb *.o *.obj *.so *.exe *.Z *.elc *.ln core .svn/ .git/ .bzr/ 
then, files listed in a $HOME/.cvsignore are added to the list and any
    files listed in the CVSIGNORE environment variable (all cvsignore names are delimited by whitespace). 
Finally, any file is ignored if it is in the same directory as a
    .cvsignore file and matches one of the patterns listed therein. Unlike rsync's filter/exclude files, these patterns are split on whitespace. See the cvs(1) manual for more information. 
If you're combining -C with your own --filter rules, you should
    note that these CVS excludes are appended at the end of your own rules, regardless of where the -C was placed on the command-line. This makes them a lower priority than any rules you specified explicitly. If you want to control where these CVS excludes get inserted into your filter rules, you should omit the -C as a command-line option and use a combination of --filter=:C and --filter=-C (either on your command-line or by putting the lq:Crq and lq-Crq rules into a filter file with your other rules). The first option turns on the per-directory scanning for the .cvsignore file. The second option does a one-time import of the CVS excludes mentioned above.
```

I suspect if it means [Concurrent Versions System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrent_Versions_System). If so, why files like `*.o *.obj *.so *.exe` are also considered as CVS files, in addition to version control meta files?

Comment: The full name of the option gives you a hint, that they are files you'd want to *exclude* rather than include in your CVS. i.e. you don't actually want them in there because they are what is known as "temporary files".

Answer (score 1):

They are not considered *CVS files* but rather *files that CVS would also not want*.

You’d usually find these files after running a build in a directory. They are not usually considered valuable. You would also find these in many `.gitignore` templates.

Answer (score 1):

You will find this list of file in the chapter
[C.7 Ignoring files via cvsignore](https://www.gnu.org/software/trans-coord/manual/cvs/html_node/cvsignore.html).

They are described as:

> There are certain file names that frequently occur inside your working
> copy, but that you don’t want to put under CVS control. Examples are
> all the object files that you get while you compile your sources.
> Normally, when you run ‘cvs update’, it prints a line for each file it
> encounters that it doesn’t know about (see update output).
>
> CVS has a list of files (or sh(1) file name patterns) that it should
> ignore while running update, import and release. This list is
> constructed in the following way.
>
> The list is initialized to include certain file name patterns: names
> associated with CVS administration, or with other common source
> control systems; common names for patch files, object files, archive
> files, and editor backup files; and other names that are usually
> artifacts of assorted utilities. Currently, the default list of
> ignored file name patterns is:
>
> ```
> RCS     SCCS    CVS     CVS.adm
> RCSLOG  cvslog.*
> tags    TAGS
> .make.state     .nse_depinfo
> *~      #*      .#*     ,*      _$*     *$
> *.old   *.bak   *.BAK   *.orig  *.rej   .del-*
> *.a     *.olb   *.o     *.obj   *.so    *.exe
> *.Z     *.elc   *.ln
> core
> ```

This list consists of files that do not contain code and that are
generated or deleted or recreated or just ignored any time that
the project is compiled.

Because of their transient nature, they are not seen as worthwhile
to copy.